# R kmeans final distance to to centroid

Tags: r, k-means

I have run a `kmeans` algorithm on the `iris` dataset in `R` using the command `kmeans_iris <- kmeans(iris[,1:4], centers=3)`. I now want to know the distance from a given observation in the `iris` dataset to its corresponding cluster's centroid. I could write code to manually calculate the Euclidean distance from an observation to the `centers` corresponding to its cluster, but is there not an easy, built-in way to do this?

Comment: Related unanswered question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397974/plotting-clusters-using-k-means-with-distance-from-centroid

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the calculations but you can return the centres for each case like `fitted(kmeans_iris)`, which should make things easier.

Comment: Thanks, this will help in calculating the Euclidean distance manually. I just wish there was a simple, automated way of doing this.

Comment: To potentially close off this question, is `sqrt(rowSums(iris[,1:4] - fitted(kmeans_iris)) ^ 2)` what you need?

Comment: Yeah, that will work. Still surprised that there is no built-in way to see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a method for extracting the per case distance. If I understand what you want correctly, you could code your own like:

```
sqrt(rowSums((iris[,1:4] - fitted(kmeans_iris))^ 2))
# [1] 0.14135063 0.44763825 0.41710910 0.52533799 0.18862662 0.67703767...
```

...for a Euclidean distance.

You could clean this up into a function if you wanted, where you specify the original `data` and the fitted `k`-`m`eans output.

```
kmdist <- function(data,km) {
  sqrt(rowSums((data[,colnames(km$centers)] - fitted(km))^ 2))
}
kmdist(iris, kmeans_iris)
# [1] 0.14135063 0.44763825 0.41710910 0.52533799 0.18862662 0.67703767...
```

Comment: Great answer! Is there a function for this?

Comment: I have a doubt:
let's consider X=rowSums(data[colnames(km$centers)] - fitted(km))
then sqrt(rowSums(iris[,1:4] - fitted(kmeans_iris)) ^ 2) can be written as
sqrt(X ^ 2), which is always same as X, as it's mathematically true.. Then why we're taking the squire and then again taking the root of it? Isn't there something wrong about it?

Comment: @SankarNarayanMisra - you're right. The strange thing is there were at least 2 other people who picked up this error over the last couple of years, but both posted comments as answers (that were deleted by moderators) so I never got a notification to fix it. Thanks. (Fixed now)