# Get distance from a data point to its centroid with Accord.net

Tags: f#, cluster-analysis, accord.net

I'm doing some clustering work with the [Accord.net library](http://accord-framework.net/).  Ultimately, I'm trying to find the optimal number of clusters to use with [the elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set#The_Elbow_Method) which requires some relatively simple calculations.  However, I'm having a hard time getting the values I need in order to determine the best number of *K* to use in my `KMeans` modelling.

I have some example data/code:

```
open Accord
open Accord.Math
open Accord.MachineLearning
open Accord.Statistics
open Accord.Statistics.Analysis

let x = [|
    [|4.0; 1.0; 1.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|2.0; 4.0; 1.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|2.0; 3.0; 1.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|3.0; 6.0; 2.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|4.0; 4.0; 1.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|5.0; 10.0; 1.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|7.0; 8.0; 1.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|6.0; 5.0; 1.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|7.0; 7.0; 2.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|5.0; 8.0; 1.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|4.0; 1.0; 1.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|3.0; 5.0; 0.0; 3.0|]; 
    [|1.0; 2.0; 0.0; 0.0|]; 
    [|4.0; 7.0; 1.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|5.0; 3.0; 2.0; 0.0|]; 
    [|4.0; 11.0; 0.0; 3.0|]; 
    [|8.0; 7.0; 2.0; 1.0|]; 
    [|5.0; 6.0; 0.0; 2.0|]; 
    [|8.0; 6.0; 3.0; 0.0|]; 
    [|4.0; 9.0; 0.0; 2.0|] 
    |]
```

and I can generate the clusters easily enough with

```
let kmeans = new KMeans 5

let kmeansMod = kmeans.Learn x
let clusters = kmeansMod.Decide x
```

but how can I calculate the distance from any given data point `x` to it's assigned cluster?  I don't see anything in the [`KMeans` Cluster Collection class documentation](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_KMeansClusterCollection.htm) that suggests there's already a method implemented for this problem.

It seems like it should be relatively simple to calculate this distance, but I'm at a loss.  Would it be as easy as doing something like

```
let dataAndClusters = Array.zip clusters x

let getCentroid (m: KMeansClusterCollection) (i: int) = 
    m.Centroids.[i]

dataAndClusters
|> Array.map (fun (c, d) -> (c, (getCentroid kmeansMod c) 
                                |> Array.map2 (-) d
                                |> Array.sum))
```

which returns

```
val it : (int * float) [] =
  [|(1, 0.8); (0, -1.5); (1, -0.2); (0, 1.5); (0, -0.5); (4, 0.0); (2, 1.4);
    (2, -3.6); (2, 0.4); (3, 0.75); (1, 0.8); (0, 0.5); (1, -4.2); (3, -0.25);
    (1, 2.8); (4, 0.0); (2, 1.4); (3, -1.25); (2, 0.4); (3, 0.75)|]
```

Am I calculating this distance correctly?  I suspect not.

As I mentioned, I'm looking to determine the correct number of `K` to use in `KMeans` clustering.  I just thought I'd use the simple algorithm laid out in [the second paragraph of this Stats.StackExchange.com answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/elbow-criteria-to-determine-number-of-cluster).  **Please note that I am not opposed to using the "Gap Statistic" linked to at the bottom of the top answer.**

Comment: You should be able to compute the distance to its nearest cluster using the Scores() method instead of Decide().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I *wasn't* calculating distances correctly, but I was close.

Doing some more digging, I saw [this similar question, but for the `R` language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498110/r-kmeans-final-distance-to-to-centroid?noredirect=1&lq=1) and broke down the process outlined in that accepted answer in my own `R` session.

The steps seem to be pretty straightforward:

```
1. From each data value, subtract the centroid values
2. Sum the differences for a given data/centroid pair
3. Square the differences
4. Find the square root of the differences.
```

For my example data above, it would break down to this:

```
let distances = 
    dataAndClusters
    |> Array.map (fun (c, d) -> (c, ((getCentroid kmeansMod c) 
                                    |> Array.map2 (-) d
                                    |> Array.sum
                                    |> float) ** 2.0
                                    |> sqrt))
```

Note the addition of two lines,

> `|> float) ** 2.0` converts the value to a float so that it can be squared (i.e., `x**y`)

and

> `|> sqrt)` which finds the square root of the value.

There may be a built-in method for doing this, but I haven't found it yet.  For now, this works for me.